# VisualStudio 2017 - always show exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Visual Studio App (Windows.Forms) that build a release .exe-App. If I run this exe an exception occurs, I only can see it in the windows log, nothing more happens.

But I would like to see the JIT Exception Window. Can I activate this somehow in VS?

Im asking for a general "If any exception at runtime - show the JIT Debugger"-switch. Is something like this available?

Comment: Why not run in debug mode?

Comment: Change build type to Debug and hit F5

Comment: Because its an released exe thats in use. An exception - as the name says - can happen on many reasons without catch every possibility.  just want to see if any error happens in productive use.

Comment: WPF, UWP, Forms, ..... what is it you are using? Also, what kind of exception is logged. This is lacking way too many informations

Comment: edited post above. Thank you!

Comment: [Debugging in .NET in Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11054183/3110834).

Comment: Sorry, also dont work. If an Exception occurs the Programm just dont start an no message, PopUp, JIT.. nothing. Only if taking a look in the windows console shows an ErrorMessage. I want this Message in a JIT-Error-PopUp as it was in the former Versions from Visual Basic .net. But if its not possible again, i will take it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it now like here shown.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/

Instead of logging made an MessageBox with the Exception Message und Application.Exit(). Works exactly as i like it to have.